# ¿Se puede pasar un operador como parámetro de una función?

Tags: r

Quisiera construir una función como la siguiente:

```
function(x, y, operador)
```

La idea es que la misma reciba un operador, por ejemplo: `+`, `-`, `*`. `/` y pueda retornar el resultado de aplicar el mismo entre `x` e `y`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algo fantástico de R, es que los operadores son funciones como cualquier otra, un poco más particulares eso si. Se las conoce como funciones binarias, ya que están limitadas a solo dos parámetros o también se los denomina operadores infijos (infix operators) ya que permiten la [notación infija](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaci%C3%B3n_de_infijo).

Para poder escribir una operación con una notación infija, hay que usar los "backticks", ejemplo:

```
2 + 3 == `+`(2,3)
2 - 3 == `-`(2,3)
2 / 2 == `/`(2,2)
2 * 2 == `*`(2,2)
```

Por lo que la función podría terminar quedando así:

```
aplicar <- function(x, y, operador) {
  operador(x,y)
}
```

y la ejecución de la misma podría ser:

```
aplicar(2, 3, `+`)
aplicar(2, 3, `-`)
aplicar(2, 2, `/`)
aplicar(2, 2, `*`)
```

Es importante notar, que son muchos más los operadores infijos que podremos usar mediante esta técnica:

#### Aritméticos

```
+   Suma
–   Resta
*   Multiplicación
/   División
^   Exponente
%%  Módulo
%/% División entera
```

#### Comparativos

```
<   Menor a 
>   Mayor a
<=  Menor igual a
>=  Mayor igual a
==  Igual
!=  Distinto
```

#### Lógicos

```
&   Y lógico
&&  Y lógico (no vectorizado)
|   O lógico
||  O lógico (no vectorizado)
```

**Nota**: la negación `!` o `not` es un caso especial ya que solo espera un parámetro:

```
`!`(TRUE)
FALSE
```

#### Asignación

```
<-, <<-, =  Asignación izquierda
->, ->>     Asignación derecha
```

Nota: La asignación si bien es un operador infijo como los otros, choca con ciertas particularidades que tienen que ver con como se evalúan los parámetros de una función lo que resulta en que `aplicar()` no funcione de la forma que lo hace con el resto de los operadores.